# Should "in illis" translate to within them?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

The Miriam Webster Dictionary [translates] [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tempora%20mutantur%2C%20nos%20et%20mutamur%20in%20illis) like this:

> tempora mutantur, nos et mutamur in illis

as:

> the times change, and we change with them

Would it be more accurate to say "within them"?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind about this translation might not be the "within" or "with" but rather the *and* here, which in the Latin the *et* might be (and this is my guess) an adverb, so it can be more accurately translated "also/too". If this *et* is indeed a conjunction (meaning *and*) we would naturally expect the *et* to come before the *nos* ("we"), but I think this would break the meter so maybe it is indeed *and*.

Comment: @d_e But cf. *Omnia vincit amor, et nos cedamus amori*. I'm thoroughly out of my depth with this sort of prosodic details, but [Wikipedia cites](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempora_mutantur) this as an example why *et nos* would be defensible, and it is indeed also found here and there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Latin *in* (with the ablative, of course) describes a location within something, and “with” would be *cum*. So you have indeed correctly identified a point where the translation is not the most literal it could be. The reason is probably that the translator thought it *too* literal to say “within them,” because “changing within the times” sounds strange in English – my old English teacher would presumably have marked it wrong – whereas “changing with the times” is the natural way to express the idea.

I believe it would not be fair to interpret this as a question of accuracy, though. Unless you believe there is some deep philosophical meaning behind the expression “changing within the times,” the translation conserves the sense of the Latin original well.